# Not getting a list of table in ajax array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong. I used this sample code in my other project, it's working fine but in my current  project when I use this, it's just fetching first values from array but I want to get all the list values from array! So I hope you understand what I am saying. If you need to ask something more about this please comment.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var degree = $(".txtcourse").val();
            var institute = $(".txtinstitute").val();
            var title = $(".txttitle").val();
            var from = $(".fromdate").val();
            var to = $(".todate").val();
            $("tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + degree + "</td>" + "<td>" + institute + "</td>" + "<td>" + title + "</td>" + "<td>" + from + "</td>" + "<td>" + to + "</td>" + + "<td>" + "<td><button  name='record' type='button'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-sm'></i></button></td>" + "</tr>");
        });
        //$("button").click(function () {
        //    $("tbody").find('input[txtcourse="record"]').each(function () {
        //            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        //    });
        //});
        $("#eduadd").on("click", function () {
            debugger;
            var txtcourse = Array();
            var txtinstitute = Array();
            var txttitle = Array();
            var fromdate = Array();
            var todate = Array();
            $(".txtcourse").each(function (i, v) {
                txtcourse.push($(this).val());
            });
            $(".txtinstitute").each(function (i, v) {
                txtinstitute.push($(this).val());
            });
            $(".txttitle").each(function (i, v) {
                txttitle.push($(this).val());
            });
            $(".fromdate").each(function (i, v) {
                fromdate.push($(this).val());
            });
            $(".todate").each(function (i, v) {
                todate.push($(this).val());
            });

            var postData = {
                course: txtcourse, institute: txtinstitute, title: txttitle, frmdate: fromdate, tdate: todate
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/GuardEduaction/SaveEducation",
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("saved");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error");
                },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: In your post data you are getting 1 Value for course,  institute.. ?

Comment: yes i getting only one list